# Angular 6 and PHP: HttpClient is not sending arrays to server even when using append into httpParams

Tags: php, json, angular, httpclient, angular6

I need to send an array of data using `HttpClient` of `Angular 6` to `PHP` server.

I have some drop down list where I chose from and push into an array:

```
arrayOfLegalProtection=[];
addSit(){
    let l_id = '';
    let p_id = '';
    let s_id = '';
    let add_date = '';
    l_id = this.formGroup.controls['l_id'].value;

    p_id = this.formGroup.controls['p_id'].value;
    s_id = this.formGroup.controls['s_id'].value;
    add_date = this.formGroup.controls['add_date'].value;
    this.showSubHeader++;
    this.arrayOfLegalProtection.push({lId: l_id, 
      pId: p_id,
      sId: s_id, 
      addDate: add_date})
    console.log(this.arrayOfLegalProtection);
}
```

The console result is showing me the correct pushed values:

> [{"lId":"1","prId":"1","sId":"2","addDate":"2018-09-14"},
>
> {"lId":"","pId":"1","sId":"5","addDate":"2018-09-14"},
>
> {"lId":"","pId":"2","sId":"","addDate":"2018-09-20"}]

Now, I need to add this array to httpclient post method and send it to the server, but as said in the discussion [of this post](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19071), arrays cannot be sent through angular's `HttpClient` library.

We need to use append, or `JSON.stringify()` or `.append()`.

I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52217106/angular-6-and-php-looping-over-json-array-sent-through-httpclient-giving-invalid?noredirect=1#comment91384209_52217106) after using the method of `JSON.stringify()` and as you can see there was errors. And even the `echo count($array)` is always `1` even if the multidimensional array contains 0 or `N` rows of data.

So I switched, for the other method using the `.append()`:

```
saveUnitData(unit_type, 
    location_type_id, user_id, number_of_hh, unit_status, add_date, arrayOfActualities)
  { 
    console.log(user_id);
    let httpParam = new HttpParams().set('unit_type', unit_type)
                                      .set('location_type_id', location_type_id)
                                      .set('user_id', user_id)
                                      .set('number_of_hh', number_of_hh)
                                      .set('unit_status',unit_status)
                                      .set('add_date', add_date);
    Object.keys(arrayOfActualities).forEach(key=>{
      httpParam = httpParam.append('arrayOfActualities', arrayOfActualities);
    })
                                      //.set('arrayOfActualities', arrayOfActualities);
    let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders();
    headerOptions.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    console.log('h'+arrayOfActualities);
    return this.http.post(this.globalVar.UnitSavedataUrl, httpParam, {headers: headerOptions});
  }
```

Using this code:

```
Object.keys(arrayOfActualities).forEach(key=>{
          httpParam = httpParam.append('arrayOfActualities', arrayOfActualities);
```

I tried to convert an object into array using append so it can be sent through the httpClient service.

At the header of the request, we can see the ordinary data sent, but the array is being repeated hundreds and hundreds of times.

[image]

And the response from server is always:

> C:\wamp64\www\dev\UnitSaveData.php:23:string
>   '[{"legalId":"","protectionId":"","situationId":"","addDate":"2018-09-14"},{"legalId":"","protectionId":"","situationId":"","addDate":"2018-09-14"}]'
>   (length=147)

But nothing was added to the database.

Please note that the PHP script is the same from the [previous unanswered post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52217106/angular-6-and-php-looping-over-json-array-sent-through-httpclient-giving-invalid)

Comment: I've enever had an issue sending arrays to an API with the `HttpClient`. Post requests have a `body` where you can send virtually any js object. Http params are params that are appended to your url : if you use post requests, you don't need it.

Comment: Btw `HttpHeaders` is immutable, so you need to do this: `let headerOptions = new HttpHeaders().append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');`

Comment: @trichetriche please check the github link added in my post and read about the issue of sending arrays using httpClients. If you are right maybe, I am having issue with building the array, so I added the method of pushing into the array.

Comment: @david yes it is already added.

Comment: @droidnation as told previously, [there is no issue with sending arrays through post](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpclient-module-vymmx2?file=src/app/app.component.ts). If you have an issue, please provide a [mcve] reproducing it.

Comment: @trichetriche yeah, but it is not readable from the server side, that's the problem.

Comment: Then your issue isn't with Angular, but with your API, since no Angular code can resolve that (even though you use Angular code, the issue is with PHP). As to not pollute tags, I am removing the Angular tags. If you feel this isn't justified, please explain why.

Comment: Your PHP script is calling `json_encode()`, which produces a JSON string. If your intent is to transform JSON into an array, do `json_decode()`. Before anything, though, ensure that whatever you're passing into `json_decode()` is not already an array.

Comment: Dear @trichetriche, I found the solution and it was a mixed error in both angular and php script, please return the tags, so I can answer my question.

Comment: @B.Fleming your comment is a part of the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Adding or removing tags isn't relevant to posting an answer (and you can do it yourself if you didn't know). Reading @B.Fleming 's answer, I think that you should instead upvote the answer he will provide, since he deserved some reputation for leading you in the right way.

Comment: @trichetriche I only provided a hint as to a possible cause for part of the problem. It was more of a pointing in the right general direction than it was an answer. I don't need any reputation for that. Thank you, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Yes, `HttpClient()` do accept an array as `HttpParams()`.

**For the Angular script**, I was doing the following:

```
let httpParam = new HttpParams().set('unit_type', unit_type)
   .set('location_type_id', location_type_id)
   .set('user_id', user_id)
   .set('number_of_hh', number_of_hh)
   .set('unit_status',unit_status)
   .set('add_date', add_date)
   .set('arrayOfActualities', arrayOfActualities);
```

As the `HttpParams()` documentation mentioned, `.set()` take the value as a string which confused the server side script even when using `json_encode()`.

So the solution was to append to `arrayOfActualities` the array:

```
let httpParam = new HttpParams().set('unit_type', unit_type)
    .set('location_type_id', location_type_id)
    .set('user_id', user_id)
    .set('number_of_hh', number_of_hh)
    .set('unit_status',unit_status)
    .set('add_date', add_date)
    .set('arrayOfActualities', arrayOfActualities);

httpParam.append('arrayOfActualities', JSON.stringify(arrayOfActualities));
```

At the PHP side, I need to use `json_decode($arr, true)`, in order to let the server script iterate over an array, as iterating over a json array was making problem for me as it wasn't able to read the field titles because of double quotes:

```
$arr = json_decode($arrayOfActualities, true);
if(count($arr)>0)
  {
     foreach($arr as $array)
     {

     }
  }

...
```

As, like @B.Fleming said:

> Your PHP script is calling json_encode(), which produces a JSON
>   string. If your intent is to transform JSON into an array, do
>   json_decode(). Before anything, though, ensure that whatever you're
>   passing into json_decode() is not already an array.